Using nestjs-seeder with Nestjs Workspaces monorepo mode
I'm trying to use nestjs-seeder nestjs-seeder with Nestjs Workspaces monorepo mode, but when the app is compiled only one file is included on build wish is main.js, so i can't run the node dist/apps/users/seeder command. I tried to add it as an asset for the user app but didn't work.
this is my nestjs-cli file:
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/api/src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "webpack": true,
    "tsConfigPath": "apps/api/tsconfig.app.json"
  },
  "monorepo": true,
  "root": "apps/api",
  "projects": {
    "api": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/api",
      "entryFile": "main",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/api/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/api/tsconfig.app.json"
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/users",

      "sourceRoot": "apps/users/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/users/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          {
            "include": "apps/users/src/seeder.ts",
            "outDir": "dist/apps/users/seeder.js"
          }
        ],
        "watchAssets": true
      }
    },
    "auth": {
      "type": "library",
      "root": "libs/auth",
      "entryFile": "index",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/auth/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "libs/auth/tsconfig.lib.json"
      }
    }
  }
}


Found the problem, It was the webpack property set to True under the compilerOptions property.
Here is the modified json:
{
  "$schema": "https://json.schemastore.org/nest-cli",
  "collection": "@nestjs/schematics",
  "sourceRoot": "apps/api/src",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "deleteOutDir": true,
    "webpack": true, <- this was the problem, Remove it.
    "tsConfigPath": "apps/api/tsconfig.app.json"
  },
  "monorepo": true,
  "root": "apps/api",
  "projects": {
    "api": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/api",
      "entryFile": "main",
      "sourceRoot": "apps/api/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/api/tsconfig.app.json"
      }
    },
    "users": {
      "type": "application",
      "root": "apps/users",

      "sourceRoot": "apps/users/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "apps/users/tsconfig.app.json",
        "assets": [
          {
            "include": "apps/users/src/seeder.ts",
            "outDir": "dist/apps/users/seeder.js"
          }
        ],
        "watchAssets": true
      }
    },
    "auth": {
      "type": "library",
      "root": "libs/auth",
      "entryFile": "index",
      "sourceRoot": "libs/auth/src",
      "compilerOptions": {
        "tsConfigPath": "libs/auth/tsconfig.lib.json"
      }
    }
  }
}


